# How to enable cookies for all browser using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project am using cookies and working fine.Here comes the problem, when cookies are disabled for browser then what to do?

Comment: SCNR: learn the difference between server- and client-side, which will give you an understanding of why your are not able to take control over the clients browser on your server :)

Answer (score 8):

You can't change that through your code. Its a browser function and you don't have any control over it.

Comment: shouldn't this be in comments...??

Comment: @PrateekSingh, I believe its an answer for doing something not possible :)

Comment: @PrateekSingh why? to risk no downvotes? nope, this is a valid answer!

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers state, what you're trying to achieve isn't possible, the client/end-user has full control over their browser's cookie settings and if they wish to not allow cookies onto their computer then that is their choice.

However, if you're using cookies for tracking user session states and it fails for users who do not have cookies enabled, there is a feature in ASP.NET that allows sessions to be tracked without using cookies.  You can switch it on in your web.config file using the following line:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

This obviously isn't as easy, secure or robust as using cookies, but it's a good alternative that will allow you to identify user sessions and associate data with those users, over short term sessions.

Comment: As ... unfortunate as the original question is, I do not see why this has to be down-rated. - Granted, I know next to nothing about ASP, but if it works, for non-secure activity it sounds like an alternative to me.

Comment: Thanks @chronodekar.  My answer attempts to answer his question of "Here comes the problem, when cookies are disabled for browser then what to do?".  I think people sometimes need to remind themselves of the down vote arrow alt-text "This answer is not useful".  I admit the other answers here better address the post's title of the OP's wish to alter the client's settings, but I think my answer qualifies as useful, as the other answers do not prescribe a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips "Here comes the problem, when cookies are disabled for browser then what to do?"." and why do you think is the asp.net-session mandatory connected to a cookie-question? this is like: "hey my tire is flat", "you may take a 5inch torx-wrench". it *might* be connected, but there's no **MUST** :) so, if so starts with "In my project am using cookies" you **really have to** ask "for what"/"why", so that you can give an appropriate answer - otherwise you'll never know the real cause, and then "this answer is not useful" applies - sry

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I agree that the question deserves a negative vote due to the lack of investigation on the OP's part. However, THIS answer does prescribe a solution - a far better cry than the rest. It even mentions that it's an insecure method, so in a way, the "why" is addressed as well. ASP.NET is not my forte otherwise, I would have upvoted this answer to even things out.

Comment: @chronodekar now i'd like to enhance my former example: "you may take a 5inch torx wrench, but it might be insecure if you do not wear glasses". `THIS answer does prescribe a solution` with this in mind i could also answer "42", couldn't i?! the main problem i have with this answer: it does not contain any "i assume you are experiencing problems with your asp.net-session now, if so ...", another thing: the OP tagged his/her question with ASP.NET, so `If you're using ASP.NET` doesn't make sense... See, the answer is pretty good, but with hardly any connection to the question - and that's it :)

Comment: I *think* I understand things a bit better now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @chronodekar hey, no problem - i am the one who's having a problem :) no, really - the answer is good, but with the lack of connection, it might be useful or not ... i've seen this so often: a guy is asking a question (really showing off that he has got hardly any idea about sth, best indicator: what have you tried?) and receives tons of answers suggesting the craziest things - so the poor guy has to struggle through x answers and trying. but if the people just would have add sth to their answer sth like: "your question is a bit vague - having problem with that, then this might help", see?

Comment: @chronodekar other guys might come by a google-search, and then trying to follow each answer again, and again, and again ... and maybe you do not know by now, but: downvotes are nothing permanent. they are here to show the author of an answer: "you have to enhance your answer", so they are kind of a control-mechanism (not only for questions) - i've tried really hard to bring the problems of this answer to the surface, so if the author is willed to either react or follow my suggestions, i'd be *really* happy!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it neither from server side nor from client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is a built in function of all browsers, you won't be able to do what you've asked.